# Vue and Django Development Environment

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-loader

I just started a new little project for learning purposes and I want to try out Vue js with Django (with DRF). I'm trying to use vue loader (webpack-simple template).

The problem is that I don't know how to synchronize `npm run dev` and `python manage.py runserver`. I don't know how to access a template that is rendered by django in webpack-dev-server.

I mean I have a template with django-template specific keywords like `{% load static %}` that is not handled by webpack-dev-server, obviously.

I know I can build it everytime `npm run build`, but that's kinda annoying and boring to wait for it everytime I want to make a little change.

In webpack, it's specified to run on a default `index.html` file, how can I make it work on the template that is actually rendered on 127.0.0.1:8000 with `python manage.py runserver` running? I know it doesn't make any sense to run 2 dev servers, but I don't know how to explain in other way.

Is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your Django server as normal. `webpack` shouldn't serve your files. It should just build them (use webpack development settings and `webpack --watch`) and let webpack put them in the static directory of your Django project, e.g.

```
// in your webpack config
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'project/static/js')
}
```

That way Django can serve the files that are run through your webpack pipeline.

On top you can use [the webpack live reload plugin](https://github.com/statianzo/webpack-livereload-plugin) and the live reload browser extension to auto-reload when your assets change.

When you are ready to commit your changes, build your files in production mode and commit the build files in the static dir.

Comment: I know what do you mean by saying "`webpack` shouldn't serve your files" and I know that, I don't want that, the idea is I don't know how to use js files that are not built yet. For example, all the files are built in static/js/dist/. I don't want to run the compiled files, I want to run the files from src/ folder. I want the same effect as with webpack-dev-server on the template that is rendered by django dev server, I don't to built them everytime, as I said in the question

Comment: It is not for production, that's not a problem, just just `npm run build` and move the compiled files in the right directory and that's it. My problem is the development environment, compiling/building everytime is just not what I want.

Comment: When webpack serves your files they are also built – just in development mode (without e.g. uglify). Just let webpack build your files with the development config (which should be fast) and let Django serve them. For commits you build them with production settings (e.g. with uglify, without source maps).

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I was just upset about all the files being compiled again and again, but that's not the case, I see now that is a lot faster because the webpack configuration does not include some plugins like `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` if `NODE_ENV` is set to `development` (I am a beginner, very new to webpack).
I just discovered a new trick with `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` where I can put the vendors. Also that `--watch` you've been talking about comes very handy. Thanks for the answer!